# Equal elements in adjacent position 2D-Array in C

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm coding a game and need a function that checks whether a play exists or not in the integer-defined 2D array (each element is an integer). A play exists when 2 or more equal elements are adjacents in position, row-wise or column wise. I've got the row-wise working fine but somehow when checking column-wise, it doesn't work.

Here's what I've got this far:

```
//Checks if in an array there are two or more adjacent elements
int adjArray(int arr[], int size)

{
    int i = 0, flag = 0;
    for( i = 0; i < size-1; i++)
    {
      if(arr[i] == arr[i+1])
      {
        flag = 1;
        break;
      }
    }

   return flag;
}

int func(int _board[][MAX_BOARD_POS], int numrows, int numcols)
{

   int i = 0 , j = 0, flag = 0,arr[numrows];


   for (i = 0; i < numrows; i++)
   {
      if (adjArray(_board[i],numcols) == 1)
      {
        flag = 1;
        break;
      }
   }

//If there's a play row-wise, no need to check column-wise
if (!flag)
{
    //Get array of column elements to use compareArray function
    for ( i = 0; i < numcols; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < numrows; j++)
        {
            arr[i] = _board[j][i];   
        }

        if (adjArray(arr,numrows) == 1)
        {
            flag = 1;
            break;
        }
    }    
}



return flag;   
}
```

I don't know if I was clear enough.
What's odd is that the columns are being printed accurately but then somehow `adjarray(arr,numrows)` fails...

Comment: You have your `[row][col]` value. If you need to check value above/below, you first check `row > 0` and `row < max - 1`, then just check against `[row-1][col]`, or `[row+1][col]`. (but you have to test to make sure `[row-1]` won't be negative and `[row+1]` won't be beyond the end of your array.)

Comment: Do you mean still in diagonal? For example: p[x+1][y+1] = p[x][y].

Comment: Consider rewriting the function in modern C: `int func(size_t numrows, size_t numcols, int board[numrows][numcols])`. Also don't invent identifiers starting with leading underscore, this can collide with standard libraries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is so close...there is  just one tiny error :

```
for (i = 0; i < numcols; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < numrows; j++)
        {
            arr[i] = _board[j][i];
        }
```

If you look closely, it will become obvious that in the `j` loop, you simply keep writing over the same element in `arr`, since the value for `i` does not change in the `j` loop, so this should be

```
for (i = 0; i < numcols; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < numrows; j++)
        {
            arr[j] = _board[j][i];
        }
```

That being said, some of the other approaches given here are worth examining too, I just thought you would like to know why your code was not quite working.

Comment: The learning is probably the most effective when you are able to produce a "light bulb - On" moment by showing just how close they were. Good way to educate.

Comment: Thank you, I totally agree.  He obviously put a lot of effort into his code and it can be great reinforcement to see that you really did have the right idea, as well as seeing other, more experienced approaches.

Comment: Oh wow :o.... I don't know how efficient my code is compared to the other solutions but I sure am glad I was so close! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

For the columns if you just need to check if 2 continous elements are equal, you onle need to

```
for(j = 0 ; j < numcols && !flag ; j++){
   for(i = 0 ; i < numrows -1 && !flag ; i++){
       if( _board[i][j] == _board[i+1][j])
         flag= 1;
   }
}
```

By the way i recomend you to use the flag as a condition in the for, so when you change it to 1 ( you found the element you want) it will pop out from the cycle without need to use a break. I found this way more elegant.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: This code, even though it does what you want ( as far as i understood your post) is a bit inefficient since the outside cycle is the columns one, which reduce the spatial location, increasing the execution time. But i think this is the simpler way to do it

Answer (score 2):

I didn't test it so maybe there are some bugs.

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <assert.h>

// size_t must be used for size, board[][X] should be avoid write (*board)[X] instead
// use bool if you want return true or false
bool func(int (*board)[MAX_BOARD_POS], size_t numrows, size_t numcols)
{
    // could be just if depend or what you want
    assert(numrows != 0 && numcols != 0);
    // we loop on the first row manualy because board[0 - 1] will not make sense
    for (size_t j = 1; j < numcols; j++) { // declare for loop increment IN the for loop
        if (board[0][j] == board[0][j - 1])
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    // we loop on the remains rows
    for (size_t i = 1; i < numrows; i++)
    {
        // we do the first manualy because board[i][0 - 1] will not make sense
        if (board[i][0] == board[i - 1][0])
        {
            return true;
        }
        // we can finnaly check the two case in the same loop
        for (size_t j = 1; j < numcols; j++) {
            if (board[i][j] == board[i][j - 1] || board[i][j] == board[i - 1][j])
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it does work but had to change the size_t's to int's (why's that). Also why make it a bool function over an int function?